# Bind selected option value to model inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

When I'm binding an option value to a model this way, it works. 
`{{profile_filter}}` will contain `{{option.label}}` :

```
<select ng-model="profile_filter">
<option ng-repeat="option in showCase.filters" value="{{option.label}}">
{{option.label}}
</option>            
</select> 

// Show Selected Option :
<div>{{profile_filter}}</div>
```

With `ng-repeat` I added additional `<select>` dropdown menus, and as expected `{{profile_filter}}`  is now empty. Logic tells it has to do with `ng-model="profile_filter"` not having a unique scope anymore :

```
<div class="filters" ng-repeat="filter in showCase.filters">  
<label>{{filter.label}}
<select ng-model="profile_filter">
<option ng-repeat="option in filter.options" value="{{option.label}}">
{{option.label}}
</option>            
</select>          
</label>           
</div>

// Empty
<div>{{profile_filter}}</div>
```

**Question :** What approach should I take to solve this? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want `profile_filter` to be since you have multiple selectors, but if you want you could make profile_filter an array, and bind each select to its own value in that array.

http://jsfiddle.net/3c70sqdt/

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div class="filters" ng-repeat="filter in showCase.filters">
        <label>{{filter.label}}
            <!-- bind to a specific index in the controller array using $index -->
            <select ng-model="profile_filter[$index]">
                <option ng-repeat="option in filter.options" value="{{option.label}}">{{option.label}}</option>
            </select>
        </label>
    </div>
    <!-- display the first value -->
    <div>{{profile_filter[0]}}</div>
</div>
```

if you set up your controller with a new scope array, the div above will display either A or B using the showCase data below.

```
$scope.profile_filter = [];
$scope.showCase = {
    filters: [
    {
        label: 'hello',
        options: [ { label: 'A' }, { label: 'B' }]
    },
    {
        label: 'hello again',
        options: [ { label: 'C' }, { label: 'D' }]
    }]
};
```